# Incomplete final line found issue

Tags: r, shiny

I have to create few filters in Shiny App. I am using pickerInputs and for every variable filter works, but for one column - 'Company Name' it doesn't. There is a warning:

```
Warning in readLines(textConn, encoding = "UTF-8") :
  incomplete final line found on ''
```

To create filters I am using dataframe from previously created workspace. I can print this column without any issues, but if I open app with this filter there is the warning and entire application freezes.

Way how I create filters:

```
pickerInput("selectCompany", "Company name", sort(as.character(unique(data$company_name)), na.last = TRUE)
            selected = sort(as.character(unique(data$company_name)), na.last = TRUE)
            options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `live-search` = TRUE), multiple = TRUE)
```

Do you have any ideas why this issue occurs and how I can solve it?

Comment: So in your file that you reading in, make sure you have an empty space as the last line

Comment: I checked last row of dataframe and there aren't any empty spaces

Comment: please provide the file you're reading in as the error is in `readLines`

Comment: I think that I found cause of the issue. Some lines contain apostrophe which is marked as \032 in data frame. It shows properly in view(data), but not in shiny. I have to find a way to find them and remove.